# sharepoint online workflow activity crash

Tags: sharepoint, android-activity, crash, workflow

I have a workflow similar to the one from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288072.aspx.

Most of the time it works great. Sometimes however, it crashes and then says "An error has occurred in workflow CreateSiteFlow". The site then has been created successfully.

I found some references to the same problem, but all say to look at the log files. How does this work for SharePoint Online, or has someone guidelines for what could be wrong?

I found some references online about time-outs regarding to workflows. But I cannot find any specifics about this, and also I'm unable to see long time (including seconds, or even more precise) in the reports of the workflow..

Regards, 
Matthijs ter Woord